# gcc -std=c++20 compiler flag -Wrestrict not understood. Is the warning justified?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++20

the following piece of code compiles fine with gcc 11.3.0.

```
#include <string>

std::string homeName( const std::string& home, std::string surl )
{
   if ( surl.find( home ) == 0 )
   {
      surl.replace( 0, home.size(), "~" ); // shorten url by replacing $HOME with "~"
   }

   return surl;
}
```

That is, if a string surl starts with the value of home, replace the head with a tilde, "~".
However, when I switched to gcc 12.2.1, there is a warning (-Wrestrict, included in -Wall) which I do not understand. The warning is for the line with the replace command.
The full message (almost unreadable, as usual) is given below, but first the outcome of some trials: I trimmed the full compiler command to the essential parts.

```
gcc11  -Wrestrict -O2 -std=c++20 -c file.cpp        # Ok, with/without optimisations. 
gcc12  -Wrestrict -O2 -std=c++20 -c file.cpp        # warning, but not with std=c++17
gcc12  -Wrestrict =O1 -std=c++20 -c file.cpp        # Ok
```

From the manual:
-Wrestrict: Warn when an object referenced by a restrict-qualified parameter (or, in C++, a __restrict-qualified parameter) is aliased by another argument, or when copies between such objects overlap.
However, I do not really understand how this applies to the above piece of code. Can somebody explain what is going on?

Here is some sample output:

```
[655] build> g++ --version
g++ (SUSE Linux) 12.2.1 20220830 [revision e927d1cf141f221c5a32574bde0913307e140984]
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

[655] build> g++ -Wrestrict -O2 -std=c++20 -c file.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/12/string:40,
                 from file.cpp:1:
In static member function ‘static constexpr std::char_traits<char>::char_type* std::char_traits<char>::copy(char_type*, const char_type*, std::size_t)’,
    inlined from ‘static constexpr void std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_S_copy(_CharT*, const _CharT*, size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/basic_string.h:423:21,
    inlined from ‘static constexpr void std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_S_copy(_CharT*, const _CharT*, size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/basic_string.h:418:7,
    inlined from ‘constexpr std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Allocator>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_M_replace(size_type, size_type, const _CharT*, size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/basic_string.tcc:532:22,
    inlined from ‘constexpr std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::replace(size_type, size_type, const _CharT*, size_type) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/basic_string.h:2171:19,
    inlined from ‘constexpr std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::replace(size_type, size_type, const _CharT*) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]’ at /usr/include/c++/12/bits/basic_string.h:2196:22,
    inlined from ‘std::string homeName(const std::string&, std::string)’ at file.cpp:7:19:
/usr/include/c++/12/bits/char_traits.h:431:56: warning: ‘void* __builtin_memcpy(void*, const void*, long unsigned int)’ accessing 9223372036854775810 or more bytes at offsets [2, 9223372036854775807] and 1 may overlap up to 9223372036854775813 bytes at offset -3 [-Wrestrict]
  431 |         return static_cast<char_type*>(__builtin_memcpy(__s1, __s2, __n));
      |                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[656] build>
```

Comment: "The warning is for the line with the replace command. The full message (almost unreadable, as usual)" - I wouldn't say compiler warnings are unreadable - actually quite the opposite. Once you learn *how to* read them, you'll find that there's usually a *ton* of useful and relevant information packed into them.

Comment: Sure, you are right. I withdraw my remark. It is just annoying that to find the offending line of code one needs to go through so many detail, which  is often not needed to find the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

What's going on is an obvious gcc bug. There's nothing wrong with the shown code (except for unrelated bugs mentioned below). The same diagnostic started popping up from my own code, after switching to gcc 12.

I suspect that this specific case is another instance of [bug 100366](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100366) which first appeared in gcc 11, but seems to have become more widespread in gcc 12 as a result of additional internal compiler optimizations tripping up on it.

The warning seems to be harmless. But it's annoying. So far, with my own code, I've been successful in coming up with tweaks that make it go away. In this case I don't get this warning if I rewrite this to:

```
   if ( surl.find( home ) == 0 )
   {
       surl="~" + surl.substr(home.size());
   }
```

> That is, if a string surl starts with the value of home, replace the
> head with a tilde,

If that's the case then the shown code slightly misses the mark. Because if my `home` directory is `/home/sam`, this replaces `/home/samv/foo` with `~v/foo`, which is clearly wrong (your original version also suffers the same bug).

So, in addition to fixing the compiler warning you should also think hard what the correct logic should be here, too. It's not as straightforward as it might appear, on the first glance. Filenames are not just random strings. They have structure, and a little bit of organization to them.

Comment: ABout the bug you mentioned: you are right. I just went a bit too far in creating a minimal example that  still showed the issue.
However, your remark about the find-function I do not understand: if find returns a position 0, and I compare this number with 0, then I know the substring is indeed the beginning of the given string?

Comment: That is true, I stand corrected, but the 2nd issue I mentioned, originally, is still true.

Comment: Acknowledged. I hadn't considered that!